# Seleccionar variables numéricas en un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Estaba buscando una forma de seleccionar solamente las  variables numéricas en un dataframe en R.
En principio la idea es usar la función apply con MARGIN=2 y aplicarle la función is.numeric.
Pero me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de por que sale FALSE, cuando aplico la función y no cuando lo aplico a un solo vector?

Aparte hay algún otro método de seleccionar solamente las variables numéricas ( o cualquier otro tipo de variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply()` tiene la particularidad que espera como entrada un `array` o una matriz, por lo que el `data.frame` se trata como tal, esto es promoviendo todos los tipos de datos a uno que que sea consistente con toda la información, es decir un `character`:

```
apply(ISLR::Carseats, 2, class)

      Sales   CompPrice      Income Advertising  Population       Price   ShelveLoc         Age   Education 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" 
      Urban          US 
"character" "character"
```

Resumiendo `apply()` no te sirve para esto, necesitas usar `lapply()` que considera cada columna de forma independiente, o su función hermana `sapply()` para obtener un vector:

```
sapply(ISLR::Carseats, is.numeric)

      Sales   CompPrice      Income Advertising  Population       Price   ShelveLoc         Age   Education 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE 
      Urban          US 
      FALSE       FALSE
```

Si ya conoces `tidyverse` una forma mucho más clara sería hacer algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

ISLR::Carseats %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric)
```